# Selecting value from placeholder, Not working using Action Class Any other Suggestion, Can it be done using Java Script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, placeholder

I am trying to automate place holder in a page Say for example Paytm site

In the postpaid option on homepage i am selecting the Operators place holder using action class as below

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div[1]/input"));
        Actions Mouse = new Actions(driver);
        Actions seriesOfAction = 
                Mouse.moveToElement(element)
                    .click()
                    .keyDown(element,Keys.SHIFT)
           .sendKeys(element,"Airtel")
           .sendKeys(element,Keys.ENTER);
        Action More = seriesOfAction.build();
        More.perform();
```

this piece of code is not working, 
Any other suggestion ? to use java script ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to select required option:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Customer Care (24x7): 9643-979797']")));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-reactid='168']"));
element.sendKeys('Aircel');
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[.='Aircel']")));
element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Action Class here. Just Wait for Element to be visible and it will click on Airtel.
I ran the following code, Just try at your end.

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://paytm.com/billpay");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='input_4']")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchOperator']/div[2]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchOperator']/div[2]")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

I have Use simple `Wait`, you can still use the differnet types of Wait available under selenium.

Happy Learning :-)

Answer (score 0):

using combination of wait and clicking on the field, i achieved the desired result

Below is my code

```
@Test
    public void PayTest(){



           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 200);

           WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/label/span")));
           element.click();

WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 200);

           WebElement element1 = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[1]/input")));
           element1.sendKeys("9108010400");
          // Select select = new Select(
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div[1]/input")).click();
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 200);

           WebElement element2 = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/span")));
           element2.click();
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("kar");

WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 200);

           WebElement element3 = wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/div/div[2]/ul/li/span/b")));
           element3.click();
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[4]/div/div/input")).sendKeys("300");  
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='app']/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/button")).click();
```